# Customized Sitemap Generate

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler, sitemap, laravel-sitemap

I have created sitemap using this library https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap
but i don't want **changefreq** info.how to disable.can't find in repository

```
SitemapGenerator::create(url('/'))->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
```

**Result**

```
<url>
    <loc>http://the-frenemy.local</loc>
    <lastmod>2021-04-16T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```

One more change set priority is 1 only home page.. all other pages set 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish resource views

Then edit file: https://github1s.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/blob/HEAD/resources/views/url.blade.php

```php
<url>
    @if (! empty($tag->url))
    <loc>{{ url($tag->url) }}</loc>
    @endif
@if (count($tag->alternates))
@foreach ($tag->alternates as $alternate)
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $alternate->locale }}" href="{{ url($alternate->url) }}" />
    @endforeach
@endif
@if (! empty($tag->lastModificationDate))
    <lastmod>{{ $tag->lastModificationDate->format(DateTime::ATOM) }}</lastmod>
@endif

    // remove this
    @if (! empty($tag->changeFrequency))
    <changefreq>{{ $tag->changeFrequency }}</changefreq>
    @endif
    // remove this

@if (! empty($tag->priority))
    <priority>{{ number_format($tag->priority,1) }}</priority>
    @endif
</url>
```

Comment: thanx  Chung any idea how to  Set priority for different URL's?

Comment: ```SitemapGenerator::create('https://example.com')->getSitemap()->add(Url::create('/extra-page')->setPriority(0.1))->writeToFile($path);
```
use setPriority method support
```->setPriority(0.1))```

Comment: SitemapGenerator::create(url('/'))->getSitemap()->add(Url::create(url('/'))->setPriority(0.9))->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
this statement Not changing the Priority of base url

Comment: @FrederickaHartman To edit it is very complicated, if you know about php, I will explain as follows:
$sitemap = SitemapGenerator::create('https://example.com')->getSitemap();
$sitemap is instanceof Spatie\Sitemap\Sitemap.
To edit the priority we have to edit each item in array $sitemap->tags.
But $tags is protected property and only the getTags method is not supported by the setTags method.

Comment: So what we do.. $sitemapTags = $sitemap->getTags(); $newSitemap = Sitemap::create();  foreach ($sitemapTags as $tag) { ```$tag->setPriority(0.5);``` $newSitemap->add($tag); } ```$newSitemap->writeToFile($path);```

Comment: The command to publish the views is this: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider" --tag="sitemap-views